# Price calculator for small wine e-shop with multiple warehouses in different countries

Tags: magento2, checkout, third-party-module, architecture

**Problem:**

My friend runs some small wineries in Italy and owns 3-4 small warehouses in different European countries. He wants his online customers (wine buyers) to decide from which warehouse they want to get the wine, by comparing shipment prices.

If customer is located in the same country as warehouse, it's highly preferable to have integration with local delivery services and online payment systems.

Currently I'm leaning towards Magento 2.3 + PWA Studio.

**Question**:

Is it possible to achieve this functionality of such price calculator without creating custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can use table rates for shipping method and you can choose price destination rules 
[here is the documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html)